# Calc 2: Integration by Parts w/ trig identities

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int e^{3\theta}\sec^4(e^{3\theta})\tan^{11}(e^{3\theta})d\theta$$
I just want to make sure that I'm doing this correctly so that I can understand the material. I would also appreciate any tips or shortcuts for this type of problem!

So I started off with substitution:
$$x=e^{3\theta},\;dx=3e^{3\theta}d\theta,\;d\theta=\frac13\frac1xdx$$
To get:
$$\frac13\int\frac xx \sec^4x\tan^{11}xdx \Rightarrow 
\frac13\int\sec^4x\tan^{11}xdx$$
Since $\tan^{odd}$:
$$u=\sec x,\;du=\sec x\tan x\;dx$$

$$\frac13\int\sec^3x\tan^{10}x(\sec x\tan x)dx$$
$$\frac13\int u^3(u^2-1)^5du$$
$$\frac13\int\sec^3x\tan^{10}x(\sec x\tan x)dx$$
$$\frac13\bigg(\frac{1}{14}u^{14}-\frac{5}{12}u^{12}+u^{10}-\frac54 u^8+\frac56 u^{6}-\frac14 u^{4}\bigg)+C$$
$$\frac{1}{42}\sec(e^{3\theta})^{14}-\frac{5}{36}\sec(e^{3\theta})^{12}+\frac13\sec(e^{3\theta})^{10}-\frac{5}{12} \sec(e^{3\theta})^8+\frac{5}{18} \sec(e^{3\theta})^{6}-\frac{1}{12} \sec(e^{3\theta})^{4}+C$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your working is correct.  However you would get an easier integral by substituting $u=\tan x$, giving
$$\int\sec^4x\tan^{11}x\,dx=\int(1+\tan^2x)\tan^{11}x\sec^2x\,dx
  =\int(1+u^2)u^{11}du$$
and so on.